# Ice backfire effect is not working on my JavaScript game

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a simple anti-spamming tactic in my game so that trying to perform "Freeze Ball" with Cyborg Ninja twice would cause the other fighter to be unfrozen and actually freeze Cyborg Ninja back.

The code is:

```
if (myObstacle.crashWith(myGamePiece2)) {
ballCount += 1;
freezeTime = 0;
frozen = 1;
myObstacle.x = freezeX;     
myObstacle.y = freezeY;     
freeze = 0;
}

if (freeze == 1) {
myObstacle.update();
myObstacle.x += 5;
}

if (frozen == 1) {
myEffect = new component(80, 80, "https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/battlefordreamisland/images/4/4e/Old_Icy_Remake.png/revision/latest?cb=20180102221338", myGamePiece2.x, myGamePiece2.y, "image");  
myEffect.newPos();
myEffect.update();
freezeTime += 1;
}

if (freezeTime == 201) {
freezeTime = 0;
frozen = 0;
}

if (myObstacle2.x < -5) {
myObstacle2.x = freezeX2;     
myObstacle2.y = freezeY2;     
freeze2 = 0;
}

if (myObstacle2.crashWith(myGamePiece)) {
ballCount2 += 1;
freezeTime2 = 0;
frozen2 = 1;
myObstacle2.x = freezeX2;     
myObstacle2.y = freezeY2;     
freeze2 = 0;
}

if (freeze2 == 1) {
myObstacle2.update();
myObstacle2.x -= 5;
}

if (frozen2 == 1) {
myEffect2 = new component(80, 80, "https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/battlefordreamisland/images/4/4e/Old_Icy_Remake.png/revision/latest?cb=20180102221338", myGamePiece.x, myGamePiece.y+5, "image");  
myEffect2.newPos();
myEffect2.update();
freezeTime2 += 1;
}

if (freezeTime2 == 201) {
freezeTime2 = 0;
frozen2 = 0;
}

if (freeze == 1 && freeze2 == 1 && myObstacle.crashWith(myObstacle2)) {
freeze = 0;
freeze2 = 0;
myObstacle.x = freezeX;     
myObstacle.y = freezeY;     
myObstacle2.x = freezeX2;     
myObstacle2.y = freezeY2;     
}

//P1 Double Ice Backfire
if (doubleIce2 == 1 && ballCount > 1) {
freezeTime = 0;
frozen = 1;
freezeTime2 = 0;
frozen2 = 0;
myObstacle.x = freezeX;     
myObstacle.y = freezeY;     
freeze = 0;
doubleIce2 = 1;
doubleIce = 0;
doubleIceTime = 0;
}
//P2 Double Ice Backfire
if (doubleIce2 == 1 && ballCount2 > 1) {
freezeTime2 = 0;
frozen2 = 1;
freezeTime = 0;
frozen = 0;
myObstacle2.x = freezeX2;     
myObstacle2.y = freezeY2;     
freeze2 = 0;
doubleIce = 1;
doubleIce2 = 0;
doubleIceTime2 = 0;
}
```

When I attempt to try this, the code will fail and causes the CPU to be frozen endlessly.

Can someone help on how to properly do this mechanic for my game? Thanks...

Comment: If it freezes, it's likely an infinite loop. Since there aren't any loops in your code sample, it's highly unlikely we'll be able to spot the problem just from here. I would recommend you start cutting out chunks of code and running to until you find the chunk that is causing the issue. Then take a close look. If you can't find it, start a new question focused on just that one chunk of code and create a [Minimum, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can help you out better.

Comment: Proper indentation would be helpful for reading here. Should all of these if statements run or should there be some else statements as well?  How does this code run?

Comment: @tenor528 Badly. The "backfire" code can't run properly

Comment: @samanime What I meant is the "ice effect" as in "freeze".

Comment: "CPU to be frozen endlessly" means the ice effect? I thought you meant it locks up. Even still, from what you have, it's unlikely we'll be able to find the problem. You need to narrow down your code into a `Minimum, Complete, and Verifiable Example`. With what you've given us, we just won't be able to come through it well enough to work out what's going on, and it'd take a substantial amount of time.

Comment: @samanime "that" code was to explain what's causing the glitch where the "Double Ice Backfire" mechanic fails to activate.

Comment: What I'm saying is... there is so much code, and we don't know what any of those variables are actually doing. We don't know what your game loop looks like. It's just a big long list of variable gibberish without any context. Is all of it really relevant to the question? Is there other bits of code that might help understand what's going on? If you break it down and work through trying to give us a MCVE, you may solve your own problem in the process. If you don't, then you'll at least have a much better question that we can help with. As is, there isn't much we can do to help.

Comment: @samanime All of those variables (except "freezeX", "freezeY", "freezeX2" and "freezeY2") are flag holders or timers when a character gets frozen."ballCount" and "ballCount2" are to count how many projectiles you've fired, "myObstacle" and "myObstacle2" are sprites, and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

never mind, I managed to find a fix for that problem.